# Oracle: how to create a fast refresh materialized view that extracts data from XMLType?

Tags: oracle, materialized-views, xmltype, extract-value

I have a table `xml_documents` with two columns: a `document_id` column (primary key) and an `xml` column with some XML data, which is a schema-less `XMLType`. I can create a materialized view with just the `document_id` with:

```
create materialized view mv refresh fast on commit as 
select document_id
from xml_documents
```

This works fine, but isn't very useful. As you might expect, I'd like the materialized view to extract data from the XML, and for this I use `extractValue()`. I am trying the following:

```
create materialized view mv refresh fast on commit as 
select document_id, extractValue(xml, '/my/gaga') gaga
from xml_documents
```

This fails with:

```
ORA-12054: cannot set the ON COMMIT refresh attribute for the materialized view
```

How should I go about to create a fast refresh on commit materialized view that extract values from XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XMLType is (probably) stored as a CLOB.  Find the hidden column with a query like this:

```
select * from user_tab_cols where table_name = 'XML_DOCUMENTS';
```

Then create a function to convert a CLOB into an XMLType, and extract the value.  Note that the "deterministic" keyword is necessary, although
I'm not sure why.  Passing data back and forth between SQL and PL/SQL will be slow, but if you're using a materialized view things are probably
already slow.

```
create or replace function extract_from_clob(p_xml in clob) return varchar2 deterministic
  is
begin
    return XMLType(p_xml).extract('/my/gaga/text()').getStringVal();
end;
/
```

Then drop and create your materialized view with the system column passed into the function:

```
create materialized view mv refresh fast on commit as 
select document_id, extract_from_clob(SYS_NC00003$) gaga
from xml_documents;
```

I'm unsure about using a system-generated hidden column.  It works, but doesn't seem like a really good idea.  At the very least it will make it
difficult to create the object on different systems - you'll need to find the new column name each time.

It seems weird that XMLTypes don't work when LOBs work fine.  I can't find any documentation about this; I'm not sure if it's a bug, an unimplemented feature, or if there's some magic setting that will make it work.  If no one else can provide a better answer, it might be worth checking with Oracle support before you use the above approach.

Comment: Wow, thank you for this amazing answer. I think we're getting close, but when I run the `create materialized view…`, I get a `SQL Error: ORA-30625: method dispatch on NULL SELF argument is disallowed`, and I am not sure how to get around it. Do you have any idea? (The `xml` column in the original table is defined as `xmltype not null`, but this might be unrelated.)

Comment: How exactly did you create your table and materialized view log?  Here are the commands I used: 
`create table xml_documents(document_id number primary key, xml xmltype not null);` and `create materialized view log on xml_documents with primary key;`.  This worked for me on 10.2.0.1.0 and 11.2.0.1.0.

Comment: thanks for the follow-up. I finally found what the problem was: `/my/gaga` didn't exist for some of the rows. So I imagine that the `extract()` was returning `null`, hence applying `getStringVal()` was leading to an error, and Oracle didn't let me create the materialized view. To get around this, I modified your `extract_from_clob()` to test avoid this problem. I also added the XPath expression as a parameter, which makes it usable as-is.